# Algorithm to find a set of meals of length n fitting certain criteria

Tags: algorithm

We are developing a cooking app that lets users tell the app their weekly budget, their dietary requirements and how many meals they'd like to cook a week. The app will then return a set of meals that meets this criteria. We are currently trying to develop this algorithm.

Going a bit more in depth, we have a collection of Recipes. Each recipe has some dietary tags associated with it (e.g. Vegan, Vegetarian). Each recipe also has a price associated with it. We want to create an algorithm that we can send some dietary tags that the meals must have, as well as a total budget and a number of meals. The algorithm should take the tags and find a set of meals equal to the number of meals required, whose combined totals are less than the total budget sent and whose tags match the dietary tags sent.

How would you approach this (or even, which sort of algorithm e.g. Dijkstra's does this fit into)?

Thanks!

Edit: Picking will occur on a weekly basis and we should give users variety in the meals that we give them. As such, the algorithm would need to return a random set that matches the criteria.

Comment: Won't greedy do about fine? Filter all the meals by the given tags, sort them by weight and pick the first `n` meals such that the sum of their weights ≤ total weight or n ≤ total meals.

Comment: @nellex I should have mentioned, that picking will occur on a weekly basis and we should give users variety in the meals that we give them. If I understand it correctly, your greedy algorithm would mean that the same n meals are returned each time? Thanks!

Comment: In that case, I would suggest moving forward with a recursive strategy to generate all possible sets which fall in the given constraint and then randomly returning one of them. I can share a pseudo-code for the same if you like, but I must mention that it'll be a bit computationally expensive if the number of items is large.

Comment: @nellex Cheers for the prompt reply! Currently we get all recipes that meet the tag requirements then generate all possible combinations and check each combination to see if the sum of their prices is less that the total price. I guess  this is similar to your suggestion. As you mention, this quickly encounters issues as we increase the number of recipes. I did however find this (http://personal.kent.edu/%7Ermuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/Dynamic/knapsackdyn.htm) which may be similar to our problem other than the fact that we don't need to maximize the sum of the price of recipes. Thoughts?

Comment: Indeed. The solution I was proposing lies along the lines of 0/1 Knapsack the overall complexity for which is _number_of_items * total_weight_. If this figure evaluates to be a bit less for you then it is the right way to go. I can help you with making a random choice for your meals in this case.

Comment: @nellex Yeah, that sounds good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can begin by first filtering out all the meals which match the given tags and then use a recursive strategy to generate all the possible sets which satisfy the given pre-conditions. We can then just randomly return a meal set from our *candidate-meals  set*. Sharing a working code for the same *https://ideone.com/HGgOp7*

```
from random import randint

meals_price = [10, 80, 50, 60, 20, 40, 30]

candidate_meals = []
def solve(index, required_meals, budget_left, selected_meals):
    if index >= len(meals_price):
        return
    if required_meals == 0:
        candidate_meals.append(selected_meals)

    for i in range(index, len(meals_price)):
        if budget_left >= meals_price[i]:
            new_selected_meals = selected_meals.copy()
            new_selected_meals.append(meals_price[i])
            solve(i + 1, required_meals - 1, budget_left - meals_price[i], \
                        new_selected_meals)
    solve(index + 1, required_meals, budget_left, selected_meals)


required_meals = int(input())
total_budget = int(input())
solve(0, required_meals, total_budget, [])

if len(candidate_meals) == 0:
    print ("No meals found!")
else:
    idx = randint(0, len(candidate_meals) - 1)
    meals = candidate_meals[idx]
    print (meals, sum(meals))
```

where the list `meals_price` contains the prices of the meals whose tags assumingly matches the required tags. The code produces different output for the same input on every run. Let me know if it fits your use case. Cheers!

Comment: This looks like it would fit perfectly. We really appreciate you taking the time. As a final question, do you know how this compares to the subsetsum problem and where the target value <= budget, assuming that we could get the subsetsum problem to generate a different output each run like your solution?

Comment: @Beardo unless optimized, the subset-sum solution will try to generate all possible subsets of the given set and then evaluate the condition which is exponential in its runtime. However, with a little bit of pruning, we can reduce our search space as I've implemented. Also, with my above-mentioned approach, you can memoize on the parameters and hence pre-compute results for a large configuration of parameters after which you can answer queries in ~ O(1). Let me know if you need more clarity on the same.